# Dynamic Programming: Single-Agent Problem

Tags: optimization, economics, dynamic-programming

My question is about equations (1) and (2) in [Butters, Dorsey, and Gowrisankaran (2023)](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w29133/w29133.pdf). This is an economics paper in energy / battery storage. My question is about how to get from equation (1) to equation (2).

Supposedly, taking the first-order condition of equation (1) w.r.t. $q$, we'd get "price equal to the derivative of the expected future value from the choice $q^*$", i.e. something like $P = \beta E(V')$. Then "the corresponding single agent maximization problem needs to maximize the integral of price", which produces equation (2).

I'm not really sure how the first-order condition of equation (1) leads to the expression in equation (2), especially given that in equation (2), the integral is w.r.t. $Z$, and there's a negative sign in front of it.

Equation 1: value function of a group of agents
\begin{align}
&V(f,s,\tilde{Z}, \epsilon^L, \epsilon^P) = \\
& max_q \hspace{6pt} \{ P(Z, \tilde{Z}, \epsilon^P) \times q \times [\mathbb{1}_{q>0}v + \mathbb{1}_{q<0}\frac{1}{v}] \\
&+ \beta \int V(f-q, s+1, Z, \epsilon^{L'}, \epsilon^{P'})dG(\epsilon^{L'}, \epsilon^{P'}|\epsilon^L, \epsilon^P)\}
\end{align}

where $Z = X - K\times q^*(f,s,\tilde{Z}, \epsilon^L, \epsilon^P) \times [\mathbb{1}_{q>0}v + \mathbb{1}_{q<0}\frac{1}{v}]+\epsilon^L$, with $X, K$ given. And
\begin{align}
-Fv \leq &q \leq F/v \\
0 \leq f&-q \leq 1
\end{align}

Equation 2: value function of a single agent in a perfectly competitive market, taking price as given
\begin{align}
&W(f,s,\tilde{Z}, \epsilon^L, \epsilon^P) = \\
& max_q \hspace{6pt} \{ -\int_0^Z P(\zeta, \tilde{Z}, \epsilon^P) d\zeta \\
&+ \beta \int W(f-q, s+1, Z, \epsilon^{L'}, \epsilon^{P'})dG(\epsilon^{L'}, \epsilon^{P'}|\epsilon^L, \epsilon^P)\}
\end{align}

where $Z = X - K\times q^*(f,s,\tilde{Z}, \epsilon^L, \epsilon^P) \times [\mathbb{1}_{q>0}v + \mathbb{1}_{q<0}\frac{1}{v}]+\epsilon^L$, with $X, K$ given. And
\begin{align}
-Fv \leq &q \leq F/v \\
0 \leq f&-q \leq 1
\end{align}

This seems to be a pure mathematical derivation and has little to do with the context of the paper, so I'd simplify the problem as below:

Equation (1):
\begin{align}
V(x) = max_q \{ P(Z(q), x) \times q + \beta E[V(g(x, q))] \}
\end{align}

where $Z'(q)=-K$

Equation (2):
\begin{align}
W(x) = max_q \{ -\int_0^Z P(\zeta, x) d\zeta + \beta E[W(g(x, q))] \}
\end{align}

Comment: Hello Sarah,
Welcome to Math.stackExchange !  Unfortunately, you may find the learning to posting good questions a bit steep.  You can ask for help though.
Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Please explain any symbol used, particularly  $P^d, \mathbb{1}, \widetilde Z$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

You might find it particularly helpful to right click on my symbols and choose "Show math,  as TeX commands".

Comment: Thank you @nickalh I've revised the question to be more clear.